# What is the simple way to implement annotation for Html Encode property?

Tags: c#, regex, annotations

I have a class `Chart` have property  `public string ChartDescription { get; set;}`

I want that before setting value for description, it will auto encode special character.

I can write logic in set function but Is there any more simple way to implement this? Is there any annotation or regex for this case.

```
[HtmlEncode]
public string ChartDescription { get; set;}
```

Current implementation:

```
 public string TagDescription
    {
        get { return tagDescription;}
        set
        {
            var htmlEncode = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
            tagDescription = htmlEncode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: HTML Encoding should happen automatically. If it isn't happening for you, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I want to implement HtmlEncode annotation that encode special character in description.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you output that to HTML then it will **automatically** html encode it for you. This feels like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)